# Selecting a flavor of classes to implement a function at run-time?

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I want to send data and a capability description to a remote site. Upon receiving the data at the remote site, I want to look at the description and create an object (via a factory method ) doing exactly what I want when I invoke exec on it.

Examples:

1) send [3, (add 5) ] => receive(obj); obj->exec() -> 8

2) send [3, (add -1, mult 2) ] => receive(obj); obj->exec() -> 4

I thought of having adder and multer classes in some form of multiple inheritance but could not figure out anything as this involves creating lots of classes from different permutations of capabilities. I think I'll need to learn something :) templates? My main concern is to have zero conditionals in the exec() function also easily add new capabilities.

thanks

Comment: What is the reason to have zero conditionals in the exec()?

Comment: Because I'll use this method a lot and the code has to be fast. I mean I can't test all possible combinations each time I exec.

Comment: The order is not important though

Comment: I am probably just going to state the obvious... but isn't sending the data over the network much more costly than the ifs? I can think of many reasons to provide functors or the like instead of a bunch of if-else or switch cases... but performance would not be one of them. Note that branch misprediction can impact performance, but there are not that many chances to 'guess' where a virtual method dispatch will end up, so it will probably have an impact there also.

Comment: The exec function is called billions of times whereas I really hope the [dispatch] will be executed once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that you don't want to build separate classes for  different permutations of abilities, to which I agree. But can you separate out your "abilities" into a set of atomic operations, and another set of combinators. If they all derive from a common 'executor' object, with a virtual 'exec' method, that might do the trick:

```
class executor {
  public:
  virtual double exec();
};

class constant_exec : public executor {
  public:
  constant_exec(double value) : m_value(value) {}
  double exec() {return m_value;}
  private:
  double m_value;
};

class add_op : public executor {
  public:
  add_op(executor const *lhs, executor const* rhs) : m_lhs(lhs), m_rhs(rhs){}
  double exec() {return rhs->exec + lhs->exec;}
  private:
  executor const* m_rhs, m_lhs;
};
  ... and so on
```

This way you can build up arbitrarily complicated operations. You do need to worry about correctly disposing of the executor objects, so you may wish to consider using shared (and possibly weak) pointers, though that will have some slight impact on performance.

-matt

Comment: Thanks for your time. Is this going to be a parse tree in the end? I don't see how I can combine different operations in this manner.

Comment: Well, it's at least an evaluation tree. In the second example above, the constructed object would look like: <code> new mul_op(new const_exec(2), new add_op( new const_exec(-1), new const_exec(3))) </code>. If your messages are just chains of multiply/add, that should be easy to construct.